# Problems with Google Talk on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, google-talk

The Google Talk version on Labs doesn't even install.

With the [normal version](http://www.google.com/talk/) there are a couple of bugs, even with earphones plugged in the sound still comes out from the speakers (the same happens with Skype), and Google talk conflicts with my mouse button 5 (magnifier).

I wonder if there is a way to fix it, or some version with a higher compatibility.

Comment: Which Google talk are you using, exactly? Because you mention the labs version, but said it doesn't install. So which one, the standalone, regular client, or the gadget embedded in GMail?

Comment: The labs doesn't install and the version on http://www.google.com/talk/ is the one not fully compatible.

Comment: Is there any reason you need Google Talk and can't use any alternatives, like Pidgin?

Comment: I didn't know about Pidgin. It seems interesting. If you post as an answer suggesting this alternative I would accept.

Comment: More details at http://www.google.com/support/talk/bin/answer.py?answer=24073